Animated PNGs (APNGs) unexpectedly become static if over 2 MiB when using the image uploader
Animated PNGs (APNGs) become static if over 2 MiB when using the image uploader. Looks like the compressor that is triggered for uploaded files over 2 MiB doesn't support animated PNGs.
Example with this APNG file:

Output is a static PNG:


If it is intentional that such images should become static, then there should be a warning to that effect when uploading an image.

@testing-for-ya should be 10 MiB, unless you use the Stacks Editor https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/402075/178179 (I don't know which little you use. That's the issue when excessively cropping screenshots: useful information is sometimes lost)

@testing-for-ya thanks, yes, this screenshot is more informative. It's ok, I can upscale it on my side.
