The Stacks editor still enforces a 2 MiB image size limit, and doesn't support the automatic image resizing that the normal editor does
Stacks-editor has a hard limit of 2 MiB on image upload, unlike the default editor (10 MiB):

Feature request: Add automatic image resizing on image uploads over 2 MiB to the Stacks editor.

better yet, increase the Stacks image size limit to 10MiB...

@TylerH Increase the file size limit for animated GIFs (currently 2 MiB)
